# API Gateway VTL cannot access item within array, nested within $input.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, vtl

I would like to loop over and process my database items in the response template. The input is obtained from querying a dynamoDB table.

Here is the template code that I've tried:

```js
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = $input.path('$.Count'))
#set($range = [$start..$end])
[
    #foreach($i in $range)
      {
        "root": $input.json('$.Items[0]'),
        "root2": $input.json('$.Items[$i]')
      }
    #end
]
```

`$.Items` contains an array of dynamoDb items. I am getting the right output for `root`, but an empty string for `root2`. How can I make root2 work?

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: I've added clarifications in the question. Input comes from querying DynamoDB. $.Items[0] contains an item and converting to JSON is working.  My problem is with replacing the 0 with the loop index.

Comment: Can you assign for example `root3` and check if `Items[1]` contains anything to rule out `Items` containing only one  item?

Comment: Try `"root2": $input.json('$.Items[' + $i + ']')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get an internal server error with `"root2": $input.json('$.Items[' + $i + ']')`

There are 5 items inside Items.

Comment: I am also not fixed on using an index in the for loop. I previously tried `#foreach($item in $input.path('$.Items'))` but also had issues with using `$input.json` inside the loop with `$item`

Comment: Ah OK - I don't think I can help more! I've modified the title to better reflect the problem to attract the right experts  hope you get it sorted out soon.